# Use attiny as an external watchout timer

Tags: avr, atmega, attiny, watchdog, fail-safe

I like to failsafe an Atmega8 mcu despite having its own WDT. does it make sense that if I add an attiny to the circuit to check if each loop is taking a specific time, if not reset the Atmega chip?

Comment: You could, there are watchdog timer parts made specifically for this which may be an easier solution than adding another microcontroller, with another codebase. What if its watchdog doesn't work too...

Answer (score 5):

It would be preferable for reliability to use a hardware WDT rather than another black box processor with a huge number of possible internal states.

Saves the programming process as well, but it might cost a bit more.